# How to encrypta license for a software tool?

Tags: java, security, licensing, decode, encode

I have created a license file in Java code for a software tool and this file has an object serializated containing some fields like creation date, expiration date, cpuid, execution counter.
Now I need to protect this file and give it to the user so that the client software can read this file to check the expire date and execution counter. 
I know that this is easily avoidable, but with the offline licensing this is my best idea and it is enough for the other people.
So to encrypt this file I thought to use RSA, with a private key I encode this file and I release the public key to the client. So the client software, or all those that know public key, can read this file but nobody can change it or write a new file (except if he uses a new private key and changes the public key).
But the main problem the RSA key length because my object can be too big for a 2048 key length and what happen if after three month we decide to add a new field to the object?
Do you know a valid method to encrypt this license so that only the server can release a valid license? Is better to use DES or other symmetric algorithm?
thank you, regards

Answer (score 2):

Just hash the object with a fixed-length secure hash algorithm such as [SHA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) to 256 bits or 384 bits. Then RSA sign the hash of the object rather than the object itself. Append the signature to the license file.

I would not suggest using a symmetric algorithm because then anyone who reverse engineers the logic to check the license will figure out how to create their own licenses.

Comment: but with a hashing function I can't retrieve information from license or I wrong?

Comment: I don't know that you're wrong, just confused. How can adding information to the license take away anything you could previously do?

Comment: On the server I generate SK and PK, I have a message like "I am the server" and first apply SHA2 to message and then RSA(using SK) on this message digest.
On the client I use PK to decode the signature so I obtain the message digest. Then using the SHA2 I know if the message is really sent by the server. But If the user creates own PK and SK and change the PK of the server with this new PK, makes the above procedure, he avoided the system?

Comment: @luca No, he hasn't avoided the system. Anyone who knows your PK can tell his license is fake. The only person he can lie to is himself. (Perhaps you have some misconceptions of what software licensing does. It's not an enforcement scheme, that's what police and courts are for. It allows people to know precisely what they're licensed to do and easily comply with those requirements without undue difficulty.)

Comment: To put it an a more common sense way: If you care about people who change your PK, surely you also care about people who just disable the license check entirely. However you solve the problem of people disabling the license check (whether with software enforcement, legal means, social pressure, whatever) should also be how you solve the problem of people changing the PK. That's a completely different issue from the technical one of how you encode and verify licenses.

Comment: I understand but if the aim is prevent to create a license himself, I can't do anything because he can or change the public key or make some change to the software. So SHA2 + RSA is the best that I can do? I could put the public key inside the client software

Comment: @luca He can't create a license himself since there's no way he can create a valid signature. If you're going to assume an attacker can change the public key, why not assume he can disable the license code entirely? Please read your question again -- it's starting to look like you're asking a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using any available licensing solution rather than implementing it yourself when your concepts in cryptography are not so clear. That would save your time and time of your customers.

https://cryptlex.com/help/offline-activation